# How to change the background position of an element as a new CSS attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
$(".element").css("background-position","center");
```

For some reason, it does not create a new attribute in CSS called `background-position: center` and just adds it to the background property like so:

```
background: center center rgb(251, 251, 251);
```

How do I make it so that changing the **background-position** will result in (like you can do in inspect element or pure css) in **Javascript**/**jQuery**:

```
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Other than it not looking how you want it to, is there an actual issue?  Does it not work?

Comment: @Taplar It works after the Javascript is applied - however, on my site, the HTML gets retrieved after every interval (it's always getting updated) and is saved on the server as a new file. That new file has the `background: center center rgb(251, 251, 251);` CSS and it does not always display properly (sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't). Having a `background-position: x` always works

Comment: I would use all three of these:
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`, 
`background-attachment: fixed;`, 
`background-position: center;`,

Comment: @Osman Is there any different? the reason is that you set `background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251)` with css or javascript, and javascript show all of them in background property. If there is difference maybe it's because priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why sometimes we face compatibility issue among different browsers. Before, they used to be more strict of displaying non valid HTML or CSS. Nowdays, they have more tolerance to non-standard coding but they could also provide unexpected code to force their standards.

What you see is simply the way your browser is rendering your code. I think `center center` is the default value that the browser uses to distinguish from

```
center top
center bottom
```

Besides, Chrome inspector could be the one playing smart sometimes. This is an example of what's been "computed" after clicking the button in the following snippet :

[image]

```js
$('#styler').on('click',function(){
$("#element").css({"background-position":"center","background-color": "transparent","background-repeat": "no-repeat","custom":"nonvalid"});
var posTxt = $('#element').css('background-position');
var pos = $('#element').css('backgroundPosition');
console.log('Text: '+posTxt);
console.log('Like Javascript: '+pos);
//It's the same value displayed using pure Javascript
var elem = document.getElementById('element');
var tab = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).backgroundPosition.trim();
console.log('Javascript: '+tab);
});
```

```css
/*already used style */
#element{
  background-color: rgba(201,76,76);
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="styler">Change Style</button>

<div id="element">...</div>
```

[UPDATE] I added a line to this code to show how is jQuery reading the new background position value after setting it to "center". It's being displayed "50% 50%" which is the same value displayed by window.getComputedStyle().
Just to show you that with different methods even jQuery is not displaying the same property name but prefers to retrieve the computed numerical value.
which could be useful for animations, translations...

jQuery also validates those Css Properties before applying them. The code checks for any available custom [jQuery.cssHooks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) (like [these](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks)), if not it will get ignored.

To conclude, we can't control how these different programs display these properties. I think what matters is how we Set them properly.

Using jQuery to define each Background property could help you get them separated in the Inspector or override existing properties being mixed up with the one you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css variables  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

sample code

```js
const Root   = document.documentElement;

var h_Pos = ['center','right','left']  , nPH = 0
  , v_Pos = ['center','bottom','top']  , nPV = 0

btH.onclick=_=> { nPH = ++nPH %3; Root.style.setProperty('--PosH', h_Pos[nPH]) }
btV.onclick=_=> { nPV = ++nPV %3; Root.style.setProperty('--PosV', v_Pos[nPV]) }
```

```css
:root {
  --PosH  : center;
  --PosV  : center;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: orange no-repeat var(--PosH) var(--PosV) url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/926/200/200.jpg);
}
```

```html
<button id="btH"> change horizontal Position</button>
<button id="btV"> change vertical Position</button>
```